# Create an array from a SQLite database in SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, sqlite

I have a database of flashcards and their attributes.  How can I query the database, e.g. by ID, and grab only 7 and put it into an empty array?

I am using FMDB wrapper.

Comment: Please provide what you already have. There's a nice [tut](http://metrozines.com/) out there that helps integrating FMDB in Swift.

Comment: Right now I have nothing but the database.  I need to get a group of 7 rows and then use these rows for testing, then at the end of the session update the values back into the database.  Because of the nature of randomly generating words for testing, I would assume I need to create an array to hold these 7 rows in.  To be honest i'm totally lost.

Comment: Did you try to implement the code from the link above? 8) handles exactly that (the select and putting items in the array). If you only need 7 items, you would need to limit the result in the query.

Comment: I'm trying to make a test application for it, but getting errors for things like `let db: FMDatabase = FMDatabase(path:mainDelegate.dbFilePath)
        if (db.open() == nil) {
            NSLog("error opening db")
        }`  where the `(db.open() == nil)` isn't valid

Comment: if (self != nil) - is also invalid. Could not find an overload for '!=' that accepts arguments.

Comment: [Open](https://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html#//api/name/open) returns a boolean. Try to see if it is false.